# How can I implement the map function on the matrix in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

In PyTorch, I would like to implement a calculation as shown in the following figure:

[image]

In other words, this is a map function that applied to each vector in the matrix, and each function is different such as torch.sin, torch.cos, and torch.tan. How can I implement such calculation in PyTorch (i.e., without for loop on GPU).

Comment: How are your functions specified? In a list, etc.?

Comment: if you could provide an example it would be helpful

Comment: Yes, the functions (e.g., torch.sin and torch.cos) to be mapped are provided as a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over the rows:

```py
my_funcs = [torch.sin, torch.cos, torch.tan]

for i, f in enumerate(my_funcs):
    t[i] = f(t[i])
```

Comment: This is a simple code but cannot use GPU efficiently in PyTorch due to the for loop. I would like to implement the map function calculation on GPU without the for loop in PyTorch.

Comment: @DongQiao I'm not aware of any PyTorch method (outside of generic Python parallelization) to apply _different_ functions in a vectorized way across different rows of your tensor. This is as efficient as you're likely to get. Have you actually tested whether it is sufficiently fast for your needs?

Comment: @DongQiao note: Python's [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) _does_ use a for loop under the hood.

Comment: @iacob Also, pytorch GPU computation is inherently [asynchronous](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#asynchronous-execution). To avoid having a potential synchronization point on each loop iteration you should probably prefer something that doesn't do in-place assignments like `t = torch.stack([f(r) for f,r in zip(my_funcs,t)])`